# MVC 3 -ASP.NET Redirect to Different View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC 3-ASP.NET, I am validating the permission level on the page in the controller. If the user is authorised to see the page then I am using the following code to render it but I don't how to redirect to a new view if not authorised

Could any one tell me how to display alert saying, you are not authorised to see the page and redirect to home page?

```
public ActionResult viewName()
if(userAuthorised)
{
return View()
}
else
{
    //Alert Message
    //Redirect to different view like Home Page..
}
```

Any examples please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 choices.
1) Create a standard error view and return this in the else:

```
else
{
     ErrorModel viewModel = new ErrorModel(){Msg="Error"});
     return View("Error", viewModel);
}
```

2) Use a Redirect to Action which points at another Controller method which returns the Error View

```
else
{
   return RedirectToAction("BadUser");
}


public ViewResult BadUser()
{
     ErrorModel viewModel = new ErrorModel(){Msg="Error"});
     return View("Error", viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See Controller.RedirectToAction Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx